# Can I use "request/demand/require" this way?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, american-english

My own example:

> "Employee request/demand/require me some registration fee."

Comment: No, you're not using it correctly. Leave out the "me": _The employee demanded a registration fee._ If you need to specify the "me" part, you add it to the end, in a prepositional phrase: _The employee required a registration fee from me_. Another possibility is to include it with the word _that_: _The employee requested that I pay a registration fee._

Answer (score 1):

Your example isn't as specific as it could be:

"Employee request/demand/require me some registration fee" doesn't clarify who is requesting/demanding/requiring.

A few examples:

"Employees have required a registration fee.":  A group of employees (assuming an employee union or the like) has passed this registration fee requirement.

"I've received an employee request for a registration fee":  A single employee has asked me for a registration fee.